# How to use Webview?

Tags: android, webview

```
  String  fbid = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");//Getting this value from previous screen

     Log.e( "What I am getting : " + fbid);


    final String url = "https://www.fbbexample.com/abc/"+fbid;  //**not working**

Log.e( "url I am getting : " + url); Log value:  https://www.fbbexample.com/abc/59



// final String url2 = "https://www.fbbexample.com/abc/"+59;  //**this is working**

   //  Log.e( "url2 I am getting : " + url2);  Log value:  https://www.fbbexampl.com/abc/59

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);       



    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl(url);

    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            // webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
}
```

What I am facing is when I hard code the String "fbid" it works and when I try it as mention above then getting blank screen   .. ....

Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SingleFbb.class);
                       intent.putExtra("id",idno);

Comment: i guess problem for white space  `final String url = "https://www.fbb.com/abc/"+fbid;`

Comment: `This site can’t be reached

www.fbb.com refused to connect`

Comment: White space does not matter and its just example not a site

Comment: How you are passing the data to this class. post your intent call

Comment: I am seeing the value in my Logcat it is correct  Updated the code   @Ameer

Comment: i have posted answer below. you are trying to get value from previous screen with wrong key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
      public class ShowSubjectListItemsInWebView extends ActionBarActivity {
        private WebView webView;       

        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private String url;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_subject_list_items_in_web_view);
            this.initViews();
            String  fbid = getIntent().getStringExtra("idmindmaps");
            url= "https://www.fbbexample.com/abc/"+fbid; 
            loadWebView(url);
        }

        //initializes all views
        private void initViews() {
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.filesWebView);
        }

        //show Url in WebView
        public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
            @JavascriptInterface
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowSubjectListItemsInWebView.this);
                dialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setMessage(Constant.KEY_PLEASE_WAIT);
                dialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }

        public void loadWebView(String url) {
            webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }

   }
```

Comment: Getting this error W/BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 18224@saurabh gupta

Comment: @AgniveerKranti webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); add this code too and this error will resolved

Comment: W/BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 4181 still getting@saurabh gupta

Comment: @AgniveerKranti So try to add this also.. webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: when I am putting fbid value then also I am seeing these errors but I am getting the output.I don't know but the same code is working fine in another activity.

Comment: so you have to debug this activity and see what goes wrong either your fbid or something else

Comment: @saaurabh gupta : fbid I am checking in log it is coming correctly What another thing is going wrong I don't know but thanks..

Comment: still blank screen...but here also if I put the fbid it is working.

Comment: see I am getting some data from API using JSON parsing and I am extracting the fbid from there and sending that fbid here and adding the URL with fbid.@saurabh gupta

Comment: @AgniveerKranti have you tried this line in my code...String url = "https://www.fbbexample.com/abc/"+ URLEncoder.encode(fbid,"UTF-8");

Comment: @AgniveerKranti Please have a look on your log value when you are passing the hard code value of 59..you are showing https://www.fbbexampl.com/abc/59 not https://www.fbbexample.com/abc/59...

Comment: @AgniveerKrantiHave you got my point when your url is working fine ...there alphabet "e" in fbbexample is missing

Comment: thank..solved...I tried the above code with yours updated code and it is working@saurabh gupta

Answer (score 0):

Try this. this will remove the whitespaces,

```
String url = "https://www.fbbexample.com/abc/"+ URLEncoder.encode(fbid,"UTF-8");
```

also you are using wrong key to get value from pervious screen.
correct key in your code is "idmindmaps" so use this.

```
String  fbid = getIntent().getStringExtra("idmindmaps");
```

Comment: it is"id" sry for the mistake...I updated it but  still not working ,tried this String url = "https://www.fbbexample.com/abc/"+ URLEncoder.encode(fbid,"UTF-8");     @Zeeshan Shabbir

Comment: paste the complete code. there must something wrong that you doing while putting value with intent and receiving with bundle

Comment: exactly the same code is working in another activity with same code for intent and other things ,anyway thanks, I will recheck the code@Zeeshan Shabbir